# PaintComponent not working for drawing shapes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I was studying graphics and tried to use `PaintComponent` to draw some shapes,  following is the code. I am trying for an hour but still its not working really can't get reason. What is the resolution to this simple problem?

```
public class MyPainting  extends JPanel
{

    public void PaintComponent (Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 10, 20);
    }

    public  static void main (String [] args)
    {
        MyPainting p =  new MyPainting();
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);       
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I run program there is empty `JFrame`, I did try it `g.drawString, ImageIcon`  but every time nothing is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `PaintComponent` is not defined in any of the super classes of `JPanel`. You want  [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

```
@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
```

and add the `@Override` annotation to allow compiler check for the correct method.

Comment: OMG ,, i m such a looser . wasted 1 hour for this .

Comment: because you didnt add the @Override annotation

Comment: for PaintComponent(not paint..) i did add @Override  and compiler said "The method PaintComponent(Graphics) of type MyPainting must override or implement a supertype method  1 qucik fixes remove  Override"  so i removed it  , now for  paintComponent  ther  is no error when i added   Override

Comment: @JavaStudent : Actually, this annotation (__@Override__) is meant for this thingy, to be sure, that you are actually overriding a method of a super class and not creating one of your own. If you make a slight mistake while overriding a method, this annotation will help generate compile time error, more info in [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) +1 to the answer, though that will take some time :( limit barrier reached.